# CSS before or border or something not working immediately

Tags: css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, chromium, opera

I'm styling this website and I have only access to the CSS (no HTML at all)

[https://ampere-store.com/](https://ampere-store.com)

I have set a before to the features icons and give it an offset border.

The problem is that the first two icons (from the right) work perfect but the last one have a weird behavior like sometimes.

When I right click then inspect the border appears, and some times it appears without doing anything.

I don't know why or how this is happening, the issue don't seem to exist in FireFox but it does exist in (Chrome, Opera, Edge "Chromium")

[image]

```
.feature-item__icon:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    border:3.5px solid #fec414;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.salla-theme_2 .feature-item__content .feature-item__icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    flex: 0 0 50px;
}
```

Comment: You are aware that CSS rule `body > section.u-light.py-4 > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.feature-item__icon::before` uses `!important` on a few properties and that therefore the rules you posted will not entirely work?? Another thing: nobody on SO will start debugging the CSS of an entire site. Check this: [reprex]

Comment: I can see the issue in the Edge Chromium browser and in other Chromium browsers. I also noticed that when resizing the screen the added border gets displayed incorrectly. I suggest you instead of adding the code in ::before trying to add the border code in 'feature-item__icon' CSS class to see whether it helps to fix this issue. If the issue persists then I suggest you create a small sample using relevant HTML and CSS code and post it here. It can really help us to make some tests with it. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @RenevanderLende thx yes i'm aware, i have added this rule trying to solve the issue, because i thought maybe if i select only this icon it will work, but unfortunately it didn't ** i have removed it**.
another thing: you don't have to debug the entire site, you can just check out this specific element that i mentioned, thank you

Comment: when adding a normal border without ::before, it works as expected, but i'm trying to do this effect ( offset border )

Comment: It can be possible that some other code affecting this output. It is better if you provide the sample over here. Another thing I noticed that the border for the last (from right) displayed on the most right side of the screen and it gets cut in a half. see here: https://imgur.com/a/Gr6wQ1Y

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT yeah it's possible, but right click inspect on the element and there is nothing that would ever cause this weird thing, also firefox works fine.

today I have tried to set the icon position to absolute and give it padding with background color and margin bottom to make it halfway out the box like this [https://imgur.com/RVL7tDL](https://imgur.com/RVL7tDL), also the last element completely hidden by the garbage chrome.

I guess this is Chromium problem and there is nothing we can do.

Comment: I suggest you try to provide detailed information about your site. Like in which technology it was developed? A code sample to reproduce the issue. We are not able to find the cause of the issue by just inspecting the elements in the developer tools. We need to make some tests to find whether it is related to any specific CSS, any HTML element, any technology, or any framework. Thanks for your understanding.